# Notepad++ - Regex for remove PORT

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have:

```
12/20/2017 17:33:36 | 111.111.111.11:53503 FAILED uLink
```

How can I remove the time and the IP's port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/r1NCOL/3)

```
(?: \d+)?(?::\d+)+
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
12/20/2017 17:33:36 | 111.111.111.11:53503 FAILED uLink
```

#### Output

```
12/20/2017 | 111.111.111.11 FAILED uLink
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?: \d+)?` Match the following zero or one time

  - Match a literal space
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?::\d+)+` Match the following one or more times

  - `:` Match this literally
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits